# Facebook login using Air for Android

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing an app in Adobe Air for Android, that requires the user to log in to his/her Facebook account. I have been searching the internet and was able to find a source code. However, the app in Facebook created for this source code was removed and the code does not accept any new app ID. Can anyone kindly guide me towards any procedure that may help me solve the problem. It would be better for me if the procedure is demonstrated through Adobe Flash Professional as that is preferred platform. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with Facebook in Air, you have to know about the extensions. By using extensions we can login/logout in Facebook for your application. Use this code 
[ANE-Facebook](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook) . it will help you to use Facebook in your application .

Comment: To be frank, using flash professional made me a bit shaky in using ANEs. I still tried by my knowledge. But couldn't come up with anything for the solution.